# Money type field returns Dollar, but regional set to UK (Windows 7)

Tags: advantage-database-server

On a Windows 7 machine with Advantage Data Architect version 9.10.0.11, money type data is returned as Dollars, instead of Pounds.
Sometimes, it will suddenly switch to Pounds, without me changing any settings.
Everything else returns Pounds correctly (regional settings is UK with £ as the currency symbol).

Has anyone else had this problem and/or found a solution?

If I run any reports using the money data type field I can't be sure that it's going to be accurate.

And no, I can't change the field type and handle the currency symbol myself.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've found some posts in various places about the problem with Delphi on Windows 7.
The workaround seems to be to add the following two lines into the initialzation section of the project.

SetThreadLocale(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT); 
GetFormatSettings;

Answer (score 1):

Late post I know, but this thread may have the reason and answer:
[GetThreadLocale returns different value than GetUserDefaultLCID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767946/getthreadlocale-returns-different-value-than-getuserdefaultlcid/2947349#2947349)

**Possibly due to changing the locale setting when installing the OS.**

Simply changing the regional language after installation to something else and then changing it back to what you want to use seems to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you discern any consistencies as to when the switch occurs?  I can't tell from your description if you are doing SQL using ARC or if it is in your application (and, if so, what is the application written with) or if you are gathering data into Excel.

Since this is, seemingly, random more details will be needed to solve this, other than if the Advantage team "has seen the problem already".  They'll be piling on later, I'm sure, but the questions I'm asking will be needed if they haven't already seen the problem.